Discussions item with no title
Right now in the discussions page there is a discussion item which has no title.

It seems a validation is missing on the minimum length of the post title when editing posts.
The original version of this post assumed that a deleted item was still visible, this is not the case.

Interesting, it seems like a user edited and removed the title from that discussion (It's not deleted). You can get a link to the actual post using the browsers devtools

You're kidding. I honestly did not entertain the idea that there would be no validation on a minimum post title length.

Is "plagiarism" how we deal with copy-pasted homework? I mean, I understand how the school would be upset with students who are likely to try to copy-paste something from Stack Overflow right back. But for the assignment text itself?

@KarlKnechtel I don’t know if that’s quite the right term, but it wasn’t a suitable post. It was a question of the sort that should be posted as a question, not a discussion, but it wasn’t of acceptable quality (they copy pasted even parts of the UI around the problem! so lazy!) and would have been closed if it had been posted as one.

The discussion seems to have been deleted

The post isn't actually deleted, recently some users have been experimenting with discussions (probably something along the lines of calling the APIs for editing directly).
This seems to be the result of one of those, a user has edited out the title from the post. This is an actual bug though since given the UI doesn't expose a way to edit posts in discussions where you aren't the author or are a moderator, users shouldn't be able to edit it in other ways as well. This also seems to bypass validations in place for posts normally so that's also a bug.

I edited the bug description, the original wrong assumption was not useful at all.

That's... Counter-productive. Plagiarism shouldn't be edited out, vandalizing the post, it should be flagged...

It likely also doesn't help that discussion moderators have even less options at their disposal, @JeremyBanks , who are likely the only one's moderating it (and I wish they weren't).

For "some users" - As noted, I tried a suggested edit, but I don't think vandalizing posts (outside of an approved sandbox or to hide extremely R/A content) is really an appropriate solution.

That's my fault. I had flagged the post as plagiarism first, but the flag hadn't been acted on (still true) while I saw later posts being deleted, so I got frustrated with seeing it and removed the contents. That wasn't an appropriate way to handle it—vandalizing posts is almost never the right solution (beyond cases like extremely graphic images)—but that's what I did.
Removing the title wasn't my purpose, but it's a side effect of the way I edited the post. If you go to /posts/<DISCUSSION POST ID>/edit-inline, you can see a form that can let you edit a discussion post or reply, even though they aren't supposed to be editable by users except for their author and moderators. However, this form doesn't include the title or tags, so using it causes those to be deleted. These aren't validated server-side, because this route isn't an intended way of editing discussion posts, so it isn't aware that the discussion post type requires title and tag validation.
It is possible to edit discussion posts while keeping a title and tags by manually editing the form to re-add those inputs, or by editing a normal post editing form's submission target to a discussion post ID instead. However, I made this edit from my phone, where I don't have the ability to edit the DOM like that.

That's... Absurd that that works.

You're a wizard, Jeremy!

@Cerbrus It's pretty silly. It's understandable that it could have launched this way when it was initially framed as an experiment, but it's been more than a year and they made the baffling decision to roll out this blatantly-incomplete implementation to be a site-wide feature without ever finishing it!
